# Can't use iOS Simulator anymore on a specific project

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

Suddenly my project just works on my physical device.
I tried already:

```
- deleting the bin and obj directories
- clean und rebuilt solution
- reset all my debugging settings
- reset the iOS simulator
```

If I am creating a new project it debugs just fine in the simulator.

Comment: Is there any error logs?

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I shall looking for error?

Comment: In the console of Visual Studio when you install  your app.